# Select with third table by id

Tags: php, mysql, join

Mysql Detail:

- Table A  (name: post): id
- Table B  (name: post_has_relate) : post_id, object_id

Could I get the post in table A with same object_id that post_id is const? I try to write with a sub-query. Could I can write it with a `join`?

```
SELECT
    p.sumary AS sumary,
    p.source_link AS source_link,
    p.source_name AS source_name,
    p.created AS created,
    p.id AS id,
    p.slug AS slug
FROM
    post_has_relate AS pr
LEFT JOIN post as p ON p.id = pr.post_id
WHERE
    pr.object_id IN (
        SELECT
            post_has_relate.object_id AS object_id
        FROM
            post_has_relate
        WHERE
            post_has_relate.post_id = 1052
    )
AND pr.post_id != 1052
AND p. STATUS = 1
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    p.created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could achieve the same result with a join:

```
SELECT
    p.sumary AS sumary,
    p.source_link AS source_link,
    p.source_name AS source_name,
    p.created AS created,
    p.id AS id,
    p.slug AS slug
FROM
    post_has_relate AS pr
LEFT JOIN post as p ON p.id = pr.post_id
JOIN post_has_relate AS pr2 
    ON pr2.object_id=pr.object_id AND pr2.post_id=1052
WHERE
    pr.post_id != 1052
    AND p.STATUS = 1
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    p.created DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```